# Почему не срабатывает break в цикле?

Tags: javascript

Что не так с этим кодом? Вроде все описано верно:

переменная i = числу введенному через промпт;

1. если i больше 100 или ввод был отменен, то выводится алерт "done;
2. в ином случае запускается цикл вайл, который будет предлагать вводить число больше 100;
3. если i больше 100 или ввод был отменен, то цикл прерывается брейком и выводится алерт "done;

```
let i = +prompt('number > 100', '')

if (i >= 100 || i == null) {
    alert('done')
} else {
    while (+prompt('number > 100', ''));
    if (i >= 100 || i == null) break;
    alert('done')
}
```

Среда разработки выдает такую ошибку: "Оператор break можно использовать только во включающей итерации или операторе switch."
Что означает "включающая итерация"?

Также я попробовал решить задачу другим способом:

```
let number = +prompt('number > 100', '')

label: while (number < 100) {
    +prompt('number > 100', '')
    if (number >= 100 || number == null) break label;
}

alert('done')
```

Тут код работает корректно только если первый промпт будет больше 100
Если число будет меньше 100, то запускается бесконечный цикл, и брейк снова не срабатывает, но уже без ошибки

Comment: Вы внутри цикла while нигде не изменяете значение number, поэтому цикл и бесконечный

Comment: Спасибо! Теперь зарабоатло! Я думал что промпт автоматически меняет значение number. В теле цикла, в 4 строке добавил number = перед +prompt, и теперь все работает